# Where and when can I see people building a Castell near Barcelona?

Tags: barcelona, festivals, catalonia

[Castells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castell) are a world-famous tradition of building human towers:

[image]

I am going to visit Barcelona this July and would like to see one of these towers. Where and when can I do so?

Bonus points for providing a tip on how to participate in the construction of a "tower", at least in a minor role.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Castells go normally attached with festivities around Catalonia. Since these occur in summer, you are definitely going to have the opportunity to see them. People doing this go throughout cities and they even have competitions. The most important groups are from cities in Tarragona, like for example Vilafranca del Penedès and Valls ([full ranking from this year](http://www.concursdecastells.cat/ranquing-estrella)). If you are lucky enough, you may find them in Barcelona.

In the webpage of the Coordinadora de Colles Castelleres de Catalunya (an Association that coordinates the activities of the groups of castells in Catalonia) you can find the calendar of performances: http://www.cccc.cat/contents/july-51 Just go through it and check the city that is more convenient for you.

I would also suggest you to check the calendar of the Colla from Barcelona, since they are the most likely to be showing in that city. Their calendar is in http://www.castellersdebarcelona.cat/calendari/ and, for example, I see they have a performance by 16th July in the neighbourhood of Raval (Chinatown).

Comment: I have no personal experience with this topic so I didn't post my own answer, but out of curiosity I googled it to see what popped up  and one page I saw mentioned tourists being welcome to drop in and watch weekly practice sessions.

Comment: @PeterM this I don't know either. Could be! Only that I think it is way more interesting to see this show together with the music and all the stuff.

Comment: @Peter M Both shows and practice sessions are interesting on their own. If you have time and interest, I'd suggest to go to a practice session and and a show with the same "colla". It is a great way to meet local people, too.